# How do I turn on autofocus with a Pentax K-S2?

Tags: autofocus, pentax

I bought the Pentax K-S2. In first use with an SMC Pentax-FA 80-320 mm 1:4.5-5.6 lens, I wanted to use AF mode, but this not available in the camera menus. When I enter the menu, in AF settings, the active area AF isn’t available. And I can’t change MF to AF in the info settings.
Could you give me a solution to this? Or tell me why it does not work?

Comment: Is there AF/MF switch on the lens? It shhould be close to to the camera mount.

Comment: You may want to clean the lens contacts, if they aren't solid the camera won't know it's a AF lens.

Answer (score 2):

The [manual for the Pentax K-S2](http://www.ricoh-imaging.co.jp/english/support/man-pdf/k-s2.pdf) shows the location of the focus mode switch on page 8 and describes its operation on page 54.

1. Make sure the focus mode switch is set to autofocus.
2. Make sure the lens is capable of autofocus. The [SMC Pentax FA interchangable lens manual](http://www.gyes.eu/documents/smc_pentax-fa_interchangeable_lens_operating_manual(2002).pdf) indicates that it is.

If there is a problem caused by *malfunction* then either the camera or the lens could be the source. Testing the lens with another camera and the camera with another lens should narrow it down in that case.